# Относительные ссылки в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

```js
 $('.cart6 .mini-gallery .img').click(function(){
        var index = $(this).index();
        var imageUrl =" ../images/es4-big"+(index+1)+".jpg";
        $('.big-img').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
    });
```

При клике на  картинку она менялась на большую из папки images. При переносе на WordPress ссылки перестали работать. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageUrl ="/директория_от_корня_сайта/images/es4-big"+(index+1)+".jpg";
```

Comment: Верно, но ещё лучше использовать `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

Comment: Это js а не php. А js в отдельном файле, как правило.

Comment: я это прекрасно понимаю. Но если не в отдельном файле, а формируется внутри php (что криво, но часто встречается), тогда лучше через функцию WP

Comment: Вот именно, что если в теле страницы, то это уже через опу получается. Поэтому ни в коем случае не предлагаю варианты с php для js вопросов. Тем более для CMS.

Comment: OK OK )))   ......